# Printing out an amount in words (Including decimals)

Tags: java, switch-statement, decimal

This is the question :

write a program so that the user may enter an amount of money which the program will read back to the user stating the correct magnitudes of thousands, hundreds, and cents.

For example:
Input: R123.99
Output: One hundred and twenty three rands and ninety nine cents.

Assume the input amount will always be in rands and that if the input amount is x, then 10000>x>=0.

this is my code so far :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;


public class switchEnhanced
{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean corrInput = true; 
        String strInput = ""; 
        String num1 = ""; //0 to 19
        String num2 = ""; //10s to 90s
        String num3 = ""; //100s to 900s
        String num4 = ""; //1000s to 10 000s
        String num5 = ""; //cents 0-9
        String num6 = ""; //cents 10-90s 
        int intNum = 0;
        int rands = Integer.parseInt(strInput.split("\\.")[0]);
        int cents = Integer.parseInt(strInput.split("\\.")[1]);



        while (corrInput){
            try{

               strInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type in an amount : ");
                if (intNum>=0 && intNum <=9999){
                    corrInput = false;
                }
             }
            catch(NumberFormatException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(strInput);
                corrInput = true;
            }
        }



        switch(intNum % 10){ 
            case 0: num1 = "Zero";break;
            case 1: num1 = "One";break;
            case 2: num1 = "Two";break;
            case 3: num1 = "Three";break;
            case 4: num1 = "Four";break;
            case 5: num1 = "Five";break;
            case 6: num1 = "Six";break;
            case 7: num1 = "Seven";break;
            case 8: num1 = "Eight";break;
            case 9: num1 = "Nine";break;
            default: break;
        }

        switch(intNum){ 
            case 10: num1 = "Ten";break;
            case 11: num1 = "Eleven";break;
            case 12: num1 = "Twelve";break;
            case 13: num1 = "Thriteen";break;
            case 14: num1 = "Fourteen";break;
            case 15: num1 = "Fifteen";break;
            case 16: num1 = "Sixteen";break;
            case 17: num1 = "Seventeen";break;
            case 18: num1 = "Eighteen";break;
            case 19: num1 = "Nineteen";break;
            default: break;
        }

        switch (intNum/10){
            case 2: num2 = "Twenty";break;
            case 3: num2 = "Thirty";break;
            case 4: num2 = "Fourty";break;
            case 5: num2 = "Fifty";break;
            case 6: num2 = "Sixty";break;
            case 7: num2 = "Seventy";break;
            case 8: num2 = "Eighty";break;
            case 9: num2 = "Ninety";break;
            default: break;
        }

        switch (intNum/100){ 
            case 1: num3 = "One Hundred";break;
            case 2: num3 = "Two Hundred";break;
            case 3: num3 = "Three Hundred";break;
            case 4: num3 = "Four Hundred";break;
            case 5: num3 = "Five Hundred";break;
            case 6: num3 = "Six Hundred";break;
            case 7: num3 = "Seven Hundred";break;
            case 8: num3 = "Eight Hundred";break;
            case 9: num3 = "Nine Hundred";break;
            default: break;

        }

        switch (intNum/1000){ 
            case 1: num4 = "One Thousand";break;
            case 2: num4 = "Two Thousand";break;
            case 3: num4 = "Three Thousand";break;
            case 4: num4 = "Four Thousand";break;
            case 5: num4 = "Five Thousand";break;
            case 6: num4 = "Six Thousand";break;
            case 7: num4 = "Seven Thousand";break;
            case 8: num4 = "Eight Thousand";break;
            case 9: num4 = "Nine Thousand";break;
            default: break;

        }

        switch(intNum % 10){ 
            case 0: num5 = "Zero";break;
            case 1: num5 = "One";break;
            case 2: num5 = "Two";break;
            case 3: num5 = "Three";break;
            case 4: num5 = "Four";break;
            case 5: num5 = "Five";break;
            case 6: num5 = "Six";break;
            case 7: num5 = "Seven";break;
            case 8: num5 = "Eight";break;
            case 9: num5 = "Nine";break;
            default: break;
        }

        switch(intNum){ 
            case 10: num5 = "Ten";break;
            case 11: num5 = "Eleven";break;
            case 12: num5 = "Twelve";break;
            case 13: num5 = "Thriteen";break;
            case 14: num5 = "Fourteen";break;
            case 15: num5 = "Fifteen";break;
            case 16: num5 = "Sixteen";break;
            case 17: num5 = "Seventeen";break;
            case 18: num5 = "Eighteen";break;
            case 19: num5 = "Nineteen";break;
            default: break;

        }

        switch (intNum/10){ 
            case 2: num6 = "Twenty";break;
            case 3: num6 = "Thirty";break;
            case 4: num6 = "Fourty";break;
            case 5: num6 = "Fifty";break;
            case 6: num6 = "Sixty";break;
            case 7: num6 = "Seventy";break;
            case 8: num6 = "Eighty";break;
            case 9: num6 = "Ninety";break;
            default: break;

        }

        if(num2.length()== 0){
            System.out.println(num1 + num6);
        }
        else if(num6.length()== 0){
            System.out.println(num1 + num6);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(num4 +" "+ num3 +" "+ num2 +" "+ num1 + "Rand" +" "+ num6 +" "+ num5 + "Cents");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

It has a logical error, but i cant for the life of me get around it printing out decimals, please help me

Comment: You never assign `intNum` to anything but 0

Comment: Have you stepped through the code one line at a time in your IDE debugger? That is the place to start.

Comment: Consider setting breakpoints and debugging your code. You'd find the answer quicker that way

Comment: @JimGarrison is right. You need to convert your strInput and set intNum to that value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have added part of the code in your question I felt it's difficult to handle that kind of approach to resolve your problem.

So I have come up with following code to fulfill your requirement check whether it's fulfill all your requirement. Note that I have only added the decimal to String conversion method. You can use this in your code as you wish.

Note that I have added following methods in my class.

The `getString` method will return word representation from 0 to 19

The `getTeen` method used to get word representation for 10,30,40 ... 90

The `getWholeWord` method used to get word representation of whole numbers

The `getDecimalValue` method used to get word representation of decimal numbers.

You can go through the below code. I have added inline comments on the code.

```
public class MyDecimalToString {

public static String getString(int number){
    switch(number){
    case 0:
        return "Zero";
    case 1:
        return"One";
    case 2:
        return"Two";
    case 3:
        return"Three";
    case 4:
        return"Four";
    case 5:
        return"Five";
    case 6:
        return"Six";
    case 7:
        return"Seven";
    case 8:
        return"Eight";
    case 9:
        return"Nine";
    case 10:
        return "Ten";
    case 11:
        return "Eleven";
    case 12:
        return "Twelve";
    case 13:
        return "Thriteen";
    case 14:
        return "Fourteen";
    case 15:
        return "Fifteen";
    case 16:
        return "Sixteen";
    case 17:
        return "Seventeen";
    case 18:
        return "Eighteen";
    case 19:
        return "Nineteen";      
    }
    return "";
}

public static String getTeen(int num){

    switch (num) {
    case 2:
        return "Twenty";
    case 3:
        return "Thirty";
    case 4:
        return "Fourty";
    case 5:
        return "Fifty";
    case 6:
        return "Sixty";
    case 7:
        return "Seventy";
    case 8:
        return "Eighty";
    case 9:
        return "Ninety";
    }
    return "";

}

//This method will provide whole number string representation 
public static String getWholeWord( int number){

    String output="";
    int input=0;

    String inputNumberString=String.valueOf(number);

    int lastNum=Integer.valueOf(inputNumberString.substring(inputNumberString.length()-1,inputNumberString.length()));
    int numberBeforeLast=(number>9?(Integer.valueOf(inputNumberString.substring(inputNumberString.length()-2,inputNumberString.length()-1))):0);

    if(number>=1000){
        input=number/1000;
        output=getWholeWord(input)+" Thousand ";            
    }
    input=number%1000;
    if(input>=100){
        int tempNum=input/100;
        output+=getString(tempNum)+" Hundread ";
    }

    if(numberBeforeLast>0){
        int tempNum=input;
        if(numberBeforeLast==1){
            tempNum=Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(numberBeforeLast)+lastNum);
            output+=getString(tempNum);
            lastNum=0;
            numberBeforeLast=1;
        }else{
            output+=getTeen(numberBeforeLast)+" ";                          
        }
    }

    if(lastNum>0){
        output+=getString(lastNum)+" ";
    }else if(numberBeforeLast==0&&number<100){
        output+=getString(lastNum)+" ";
    }
    return output;
}

//This method will return decimal value String representation 
public static String getDecimalValue(String decimal){
    String output="";

    //check whether the decimal string contains fractions
    if(decimal.contains(".")){

        //Identify the fraction and non fraction parts in decimal
        String partBeforeDecimalPoint=decimal.split("\\.")[0];
        String partAfterDecimalPoint=decimal.split("\\.")[1];

        if(partBeforeDecimalPoint.length()>0)
            output=getWholeWord(Integer.parseInt(partBeforeDecimalPoint));

        if(partAfterDecimalPoint.length()>0)
            output+= ((output.length()>0?" and ":"")+getWholeWord(Integer.parseInt(partAfterDecimalPoint))+"cents");

    }else{
        output=getWholeWord(Integer.parseInt(decimal));
    }
    return output; 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(getDecimalValue("12.20"));
    System.out.println(getDecimalValue("2100.99"));
    System.out.println(getDecimalValue("4500.67"));
    System.out.println(getDecimalValue("23450"));
    System.out.println(getDecimalValue("15"));

}
}
```

These are the output of the sample numbers.

```
Twelve and Twenty cents
Two  Thousand One Hundread  and Ninety Nine cents
Four  Thousand Five Hundread  and Sixty Seven cents
Twenty Three  Thousand Four Hundread Fifty 
Fifteen
```

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

you are missing this

```
intNum = Integer.parseInt(strInput);
```

paste it after JOptionPane.showInputDialog method.

your switch cases don't look correct either. if intNum is 1234

then you will get

```
num1 = "Four"
num2 = ""
num3 = ""
num4 = "One Thousand"
num5 = "Four"
num6 = ""
```

probably not what you want.